# How to map Oracle Interval Day to Second data type to Java object

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to map a column in my database that has the data type `Interval Day(0) to Second(2)` to a Java object in my Spring Entity. Currently, I'm using String for my Java object:

```
@Column
private String duration;
```

From a number of seconds that I have, for example: 5400 seconds, I convert it into the number of days, hours, minutes, etc. and parse into the Java object like this:

```
String duration = day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + miliseconds;
```

The string that would be inserted into database should look like this:

```
0 1:30:0.0
```

I want to know if there's any better way to do this? Is it correct to map Oracle Interval data type using Java string?

Comment: Java 8 comes with [an actual Duration class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html). Would that not be a better fit?